# Finding the area on a graph bounded by four curves.

Tags: calculus

I'm tasked with finding the area of a graph enclosed by four curves. The problem I'm going through is finding which particular set of curves (or integrals for that matter) to add when finding the area.

The curves are as follows:

$x=e^y$

y=1

y=-1

$x=y^2 - 2$

The link to the graph is here on Desmos:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q9w0knkybu

Any kind of help with how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like rotating the graph 90 degrees (exchanging x and y) would make it easier see.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ctt9hstopa

Comment: I believe that's 90 degrees rotated, but does that help?

Comment: Well, does it help for you? Is it clear what the height of a thin slice would be, and what the bounds of integration are?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Use a double integral in the following order:
$$A=\int_{-1}^1\int_?^? dx\,dy\ .$$
See if you can fill in the missing bits and complete the calculation.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how you got -1 and 1 as the limits of integration, so I'm not entirely sure what the missing components would be.

Comment: Look at your graph.  The values of $y$ go from $-1$ to $1$.  To get the missing limits you need to look at the graph again and ask yourself: for any specific value of $y$, what are the values of $x$ such that $(x,y)$ is in the region?